# Android: data not stored in SQLite permanently

Tags: android, sqlite, service

I have an Android service that calls a distant server and get data from it, I store the data in a SQLite database, everything works fine, but when I don't call the service and execute again in the emulator, I find that all the stored data is gone, and the database is empty, is it because I run the project in the emulator and it keep data only in a sort of cache?

Thank you

**EDIT**

When I run the application the second time, it seems like data is there, but the third time it disappear. Sometimes data is erased in the second or the fourth running.

Here is my Openhelper

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String dbName="DBlite2";
static final String tableMagasin= "magasin";
static final String tablenotif= "notification";
static final String tabletemp= "temporaire";
//colonnes de la table magasin
static final String colNomMag= "nomMag";
static final String colCategorie="categorie";
static final String colVille="ville";
static final String colAdresse="adresse";
static final String collat="latitude";
static final String collon="longitude";
static final String colDescr="description";
static final String colFavoris= "favori";
//colonnes de la table notifications
static final String colidNotif= "idnotif";
static final String colcontenu= "contenu";
static final String coldate= "datenotif";
static final String colvalidite= "validite";
static final String colnmnotif= "nmnotif";
static final String colctnotif= "ctnotif";
static final String colvlnotif= "vlnotif";

public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,dbName ,null,1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //création de la table magasin
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tableMagasin+"("+colNomMag+" TEXT, "+ colCategorie +
        " TEXT, "+ colVille+" TEXT, "+colAdresse + " TEXT, "+ collat +
        " FLOAT, " + collon +" FLOAT, "+ colDescr+ " TEXT, " +
             colFavoris + " BIT,  PRIMARY KEY ( "+colNomMag+ " , "+colCategorie+" , "+colVille+" ));");

    //création de la table notification
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tablenotif+"("+colidNotif+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ colcontenu+" TEXT, "+coldate+" DATETIME, " 
            +colvalidite+" INTEGER, "+colnmnotif+" TEXT, "+colctnotif+" TEXT, "+colvlnotif+" TEXT, FOREIGN KEY ("
            +colnmnotif+") REFERENCES "+tableMagasin+" ( "+colNomMag+" ), FOREIGN KEY ( "+colctnotif+" ) REFERENCES "
            +tableMagasin+" ( "+colCategorie +" ), FOREIGN KEY("+ colvlnotif + ") REFERENCES "+ tableMagasin + " ("+ colVille+ "));");

    //création de la table tomporaire
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tabletemp+"("+colidNotif+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ colcontenu+" TEXT, "+coldate+" DATETIME, " 
            +colvalidite+" INTEGER, "+colnmnotif+" TEXT, "+colctnotif+" TEXT, "+colvlnotif+" TEXT, FOREIGN KEY ("
            +colnmnotif+") REFERENCES "+tableMagasin+" ( "+colNomMag+" ), FOREIGN KEY ( "+colctnotif+" ) REFERENCES "
            +tableMagasin+" ( "+colCategorie +" ), FOREIGN KEY("+ colvlnotif + ") REFERENCES "+ tableMagasin + " ("+ colVille+ "));");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

 @Override
 public String toString()
 {
     return (colNomMag + "\nCatégorie:" + colCategorie+ "\nVille:"+colVille);
  }
}
```

And my class where I do the insertion, update an delete:

```
public class MagasinDataSource {

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
private String[] allcolumns = {DataBaseHelper.colNomMag,DataBaseHelper.colCategorie, DataBaseHelper.colVille,
        DataBaseHelper.colAdresse,DataBaseHelper.collat,DataBaseHelper.collon,DataBaseHelper.colDescr,DataBaseHelper.colFavoris};
private String[] notifcol={DataBaseHelper.colidNotif, DataBaseHelper.colcontenu, DataBaseHelper.coldate, DataBaseHelper.colvalidite,
        DataBaseHelper.colnmnotif,DataBaseHelper.colctnotif,DataBaseHelper.colvlnotif}; 
public MagasinDataSource(Context context)
{
    this.dbhelper= new DataBaseHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbhelper.close();
}

public long insertMag(Magasin ma)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colNomMag, ma.getNomMag());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colCategorie, ma.getCat());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colVille, ma.getVille());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colAdresse, ma.getAdr());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colDescr, ma.getDescr());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colFavoris, ma.isFav());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.collat, ma.getLat());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.collon, ma.getLon());
    return db.insert(DataBaseHelper.tableMagasin, null, values);
}

public long insertNotif(Notif n)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colidNotif, n.getId_notif());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colcontenu, n.getContenu());
    //values.put(DataBaseHelper.coldate, n.getDatenotif());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colvalidite, n.getValidite());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colnmnotif, n.getNmag());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colctnotif, n.getCtmag());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colvlnotif, n.getVlmag());
    return db.insert(DataBaseHelper.tablenotif, null, values);
}

public long inserttemp(Notif n)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colidNotif, n.getId_notif());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colcontenu, n.getContenu());
    //values.put(DataBaseHelper.coldate, n.getDatenotif());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colvalidite, n.getValidite());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colnmnotif, n.getNmag());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colctnotif, n.getCtmag());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colvlnotif, n.getVlmag());
    return db.insert(DataBaseHelper.tabletemp, null, values);
}

public void deleteMag(Magasin ma)
{
    db.delete(DataBaseHelper.tableMagasin, DataBaseHelper.colNomMag +" =?"  + " AND "+ DataBaseHelper.colCategorie+" =?"+ " AND "+ DataBaseHelper.colVille+" =?", new String []{String.valueOf(ma.getNomMag()),String.valueOf(ma.getCat()),String.valueOf(ma.getVille())});
}

public void deleteAllnotif()
{
    db.delete(DataBaseHelper.tablenotif, null, null);
}
public void deleteAlltemp()
{
    db.delete(DataBaseHelper.tabletemp, null, null);
}

public void deletAllmag()
{
    db.delete(DataBaseHelper.tableMagasin, null, null);
}

public void updateMag(Magasin ma)
{

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colNomMag, ma.getNomMag());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colCategorie, ma.getCat());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colVille, ma.getVille());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colAdresse, ma.getAdr());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colDescr, ma.getDescr());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.colFavoris, ma.isFav());

    db.update(DataBaseHelper.tableMagasin, values, DataBaseHelper.colNomMag +" =? AND "+DataBaseHelper.colCategorie+" =? AND "+DataBaseHelper.colVille+" =?" ,new String []{String.valueOf(ma.getNomMag()),String.valueOf(ma.getCat()),String.valueOf(ma.getVille())});
    // + " AND "+ DataBaseHelper.colCategorie+" = "+ct+ " AND "+ DataBaseHelper.colVille+" = "+ vl,null);
 //  db.execSQL("UPDATE "+ DataBaseHelper.tableMagasin+" SET "+DataBaseHelper.colNomMag+" = "+ma.getNomMag()+" , "+DataBaseHelper.colCategorie+" = "+ma.getCat()+" , "+DataBaseHelper.colVille+" = "+ma.getVille()+" , "+DataBaseHelper.colAdresse+" = "+ma.getAdr()+
    //     " , "+DataBaseHelper.colDescr+" = "+ma.getDescr()+" , "+DataBaseHelper.colVille+" = "+ma.isFav()+" WHERE "+DataBaseHelper.colNomMag+" = "+ma.getNomMag()+" AND "+DataBaseHelper.colCategorie+" = "+ma.getCat()+" AND "+DataBaseHelper.colVille+" = "+ma.getVille());
}

public List<Magasin> getFavoris()
{
    List<Magasin> lstfavoris = new ArrayList<Magasin>();
    String getfav= "select * from magasin where favori=1";
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(getfav, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Magasin magasin= cursorToMagasin(cursor);
        lstfavoris.add(magasin);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return lstfavoris;
}

public List<Notif> getGeoloc(float latitude, float longitude)
{
    List<Magasin> lstgeo= new ArrayList<Magasin>();
    List<Notif> lstnotif= new ArrayList<Notif>();
    float latinf= latitude - (float) 0.5;
    float latsup= latitude + (float) 0.5;
    float loninf= longitude - (float) 0.5;
    float lonsup= longitude + (float) 0.5;
    String requete="select * from magasin where latitude > "+String.valueOf(latinf)+" and latitude < "+String.valueOf(latsup)+
              " and longitude > "+String.valueOf(loninf)+" and longitude < "+ String.valueOf(lonsup);
 //  String requete="select * from magasin where favori=1";
//  String requete="select * from notification";
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(requete, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        Magasin mag= cursorToMagasin(cursor);
        lstgeo.add(mag);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    for(int i=0;i<lstgeo.size();i++)
    {
        String nm= lstgeo.get(i).getNomMag();
        String ct= lstgeo.get(i).getCat();
        String vl= lstgeo.get(i).getVille();
        String requete2="select * from notification where nmnotif = '"+nm+"' and ctnotif = '"+ct+"' and vlnotif = '"+vl+"'";
   Cursor  cursor2= db.rawQuery(requete2, null);
   cursor2.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor2.isAfterLast())
        {
            Notif notif= cursorToNotif(cursor2);
            lstnotif.add(notif);
            cursor2.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor2.close();
    }

    return lstnotif;
}

public List<Magasin> getAll()
{
    List<Magasin> lstall = new ArrayList<Magasin>();
    Cursor cursor= db.query(DataBaseHelper.tableMagasin,allcolumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Magasin magasin= cursorToMagasin(cursor);
        lstall.add(magasin);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return lstall;
}

public boolean existeMag(String nm,String ct,String vl)
{
    List<Magasin> lst= new ArrayList<Magasin>();
    lst= getAll();
    boolean b=false;
    String nom;
    String cat;
    String ville;
    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
    {
         nom= lst.get(i).getNomMag();
         cat= lst.get(i).getCat();
         ville=lst.get(i).getVille();
         if((nm.equals(nom)) && (ct.equals(cat)) && (vl.equals(ville)))
         {
             b=true;
             break;
         }
    }
    return b;
}

public Magasin getMagasin(String nm,String ct,String vl)
{
    List<Magasin> lst= new ArrayList<Magasin>();
    Magasin m= new Magasin();
    lst=getAll();
    String nom;
    String cat;
    String ville;
    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
    {
         nom= lst.get(i).getNomMag();
         cat= lst.get(i).getCat();
         ville=lst.get(i).getVille();
         if((nm.equals(nom)) && (ct.equals(cat)) && (vl.equals(ville)))
         {
             m=lst.get(i);
             break;
         }
    }
    return m;
}

public boolean existeNotif(Notif notif)
{
    List<Notif> lst= new ArrayList<Notif>();
    lst=getAllNotif();
    boolean b=false;

    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
    {
        Notif s= new Notif();
        s=lst.get(i);
        if(notif.getId_notif()==s.getId_notif())
        {
            b=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

public boolean existetemp(Notif notif)
{
    List<Notif> lst= new ArrayList<Notif>();
    lst=getAlltemp();
    boolean b=false;

    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
    {
        Notif s= new Notif();
        s=lst.get(i);
        if(notif.getId_notif()==s.getId_notif())
        {
            b=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

public List<Notif> getAllNotif()
{
    List<Notif> lstnotif= new ArrayList<Notif>();
    Cursor cursor= db.query(DataBaseHelper.tablenotif,notifcol, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Notif s= cursorToNotif(cursor);
        lstnotif.add(s);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return lstnotif;

}

public List<Notif> getAlltemp()
{
    List<Notif> lstnotif= new ArrayList<Notif>();
    Cursor cursor= db.query(DataBaseHelper.tabletemp,notifcol, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Notif s= cursorToNotif(cursor);
        lstnotif.add(s);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return lstnotif;
}

private Magasin cursorToMagasin(Cursor cursor) {
        Magasin magasin = new Magasin();
        magasin.setNomMag(cursor.getString(0));
        magasin.setCat(cursor.getString(1));
        magasin.setVille(cursor.getString(2));
        magasin.setAdr(cursor.getString(3));
        magasin.setLat(cursor.getFloat(4));
        magasin.setLon(cursor.getFloat(5));
        magasin.setDescr(cursor.getString(6));
        magasin.setFav(cursor.getInt(7)==1);
        return magasin;
    }

    private Notif cursorToNotif(Cursor cursor)
    {
        Notif n= new Notif();
        n.setId_notif(cursor.getInt(0));
        n.setContenu(cursor.getString(1));
        //n.setDatenotif(cursor.getString(2));
        n.setValidite(cursor.getInt(3));
        n.setNmag(cursor.getString(4));
        n.setCtmag(cursor.getString(5));
        n.setVlmag(cursor.getString(6));

        return n;
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

Here is the code of my service:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {
 private MagasinDataSource datasource;


    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    public static ShopAlertActivity MAIN_ACTIVITY;      
    private Timer timer=new Timer();   
    private static long UPDATE_INTERVAL =  86400000;  //default
    private static long DELAY_INTERVAL = 10000;  
    public static void setMainActivity(ShopAlertActivity activity)
    {
      MAIN_ACTIVITY = activity;   

    }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

 @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
     SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
     String interval= SP.getString("synchronisation", "1");
    if(interval.equals("1")) UPDATE_INTERVAL= 43200000;
    if(interval.equals("2")) UPDATE_INTERVAL= 86400000;
    if(interval.equals("3")) UPDATE_INTERVAL= 115200000;
      super.onCreate();     

      _startService();

     // if (MAIN_ACTIVITY != null)  Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "FileScannerService started");
    }
  /*
     * starting the service
     */
    private void _startService()
    {   

      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(   

              new TimerTask() {

                    public void run() {

                        try{

                        doServiceWork();

                        Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL);

                        }catch(InterruptedException ie){

                            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "FileScannerService InterruptedException"+ie.toString());
                        }

                    }
                  },
                  DELAY_INTERVAL,
                  UPDATE_INTERVAL);

      Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "FileScannerService Timer started....");
    }
    /*
     * start the processing, the actual work, getting config params, get data from network etc
     */
    private void doServiceWork()
    {
        //avoir les préférences
         SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
         String interval= SP.getString("synchronisation", "1");
        if(interval.equals("1")) UPDATE_INTERVAL= 43200000;
        if(interval.equals("2")) UPDATE_INTERVAL= 86400000;
        if(interval.equals("3")) UPDATE_INTERVAL= 115200000;

    try{


         //call the distant web service
        soapclass sc= new soapclass("TabMag");
        soapclass cs= new soapclass("TabNotif");
        Magasin[] tab_mag=sc.get_table_magasin();
        Notif[] tab_notif=cs.get_table_notif();


         datasource = new MagasinDataSource(this); 
         datasource.open();


         //Delete existing data
         if(tab_mag.length>0)
         {
            // datasource.deletAllmag();
            // datasource.deleteAllnotif();
         }


         //Insert data received from web service in table magasin
         for(int i=0;i<tab_mag.length;i++)
         {
             Magasin m= new Magasin();
             m=tab_mag[i];
             if(lst_fav.contains(m))
             {
                 m.setFav(true);
             }
             datasource.insertMag(m);
         }
         //insert data in tab_notif
         for(int i=0;i<tab_notif.length;i++)
         {
             Notif n= new Notif();
             n= tab_notif[i];
             datasource.insertNotif(n);
         }
         datasource.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }



    }
    /*
     * shutting down the service
     */
    private void _shutdownService()
    {
      if (timer != null) timer.cancel();

     // Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Timer stopped...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you clearing your db everytime your app starts?

Comment: in my service I was clearing my DB to add the new data, but in the second time I didn't call my service, so I think I don't

Comment: if I don't close my db, can that be the source of the problem? I tried to close it but maybe I'm doing it the wrong wat

Comment: Forgetting to close your database shouldn't clear any data. Please post you database adapter and OpenHelper classes so we can see what is happening.

Comment: At first glance, I don't see anything wrong... Does the database disappear each time you start your emulator? (If so, uncheck "Wipe user data" in the emulator's launch dialog.) I assume that you are not calling delete*() on all the tables at any point?

Comment: No I don't call delete, I think that it comes from my service, the service calls a server and get data, but even when the server applciation is off, the service gets data anyways, seems like it store data in a cache. and when the service isn't working, there's no data!

Comment: Interesting, could you post the service as well?

Comment: edited, I've posted my service, I'm using ksoap2 to call my distant webservice and get data.

Comment: From what you have posted, I don't see any reason why the Service should clear the database. You could have a SQL Insertion attack here: `String requete2="select * from notification where nmnotif = '"+nm+"' and ctnotif = '"+ct+"' and vlnotif = '"+vl+"'";` or something somewhere else in your code that you haven't included...

Comment: ok, I will search more, thank you soo much for your help :)

Comment: I found that my database is recreated each time that I run the app, the problem has nothing to do with the service, any ideas why the database is recreated?